# Android Hilt with ViewModel scoped to Navgraph, Provider Factory issue

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-jetpack, dagger-hilt

I am using **Hilt** for **Dependency Injection** specially for injecting into **ViewModel**.
Also wanted to **scope ViewModel to NavGraph**. To do this, got the **ViewModelStoreOwner** by passing the **NavGraph** and now creating **ViewModel** by passing the **store instance provided by the navgraph** to **ViewModelProvider**. The problem I'm facing is, as I'm passing only the **store instance** to get the **ViewModelProvider** without any **Factory**, since **Hilt** will implement that, I'm getting build error **has no zero argument constructor**. When saw the source code I found that as I'm providing only **store instance** as an argument and no factory, **a simple factory is being provided automatically** and as the **provided factory has no arguments**, hence this error.

**How to solve this?**

**The method being called from source (ViewModelProvider.java)**-

```
     * Creates {@code ViewModelProvider}. This will create {@code ViewModels}
     * and retain them in a store of the given {@code ViewModelStoreOwner}.
     * <p>
     * This method will use the
     * {@link HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory#getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory() default factory}
     * if the owner implements {@link HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory}. Otherwise, a
     * {@link NewInstanceFactory} will be used.
     */
    public ViewModelProvider(@NonNull ViewModelStoreOwner owner) {
        this(owner.getViewModelStore(), owner instanceof HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory
                ? ((HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory) owner).getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory()
                : NewInstanceFactory.getInstance());
    }
```

**My ViewModel Class that requires dependency injection**-

```
    private Repository repository;
    private MutableLiveData<FeatureCollection> featureCollection = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> loading = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private Disposable disposable;


    @ViewModelInject
    public QuakeListViewModel(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
```

**My Fragment class**-

```
    private FragmentQuakeListBinding _binding;
    private QuakeListViewModel _viewModel;
    private ViewModelStoreOwner viewModelStoreOwner;
    private NavController _navController;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
        viewModelStoreOwner =  _navController.getViewModelStoreOwner(R.id.main_nav_graph);

    }
```

```
public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //other implementation
        _viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(viewModelStoreOwner).get(QuakeListViewModel.class);
        //return binding.root
    }
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Integration with the Jetpack navigation library documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#viewmodel-navigation):

> If your ViewModel is [scoped to the navigation graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel), use the `defaultViewModelProviderFactory` object that is available to activities and fragments that are annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint`.

So you can use:

```
_viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(viewModelStoreOwner,
    getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory()).get(QuakeListViewModel.class);
```

Comment: Is it changed to `hiltNavGraphViewModels` if we are using hilt for DI?

Comment: @nabeel - yep, that API is a convenience wrapper that does this call for you.

Comment: @Nabeel you have to implement the dependency for using `hiltNavGraphViewModels` i.e. `implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0'`